# Why does filtering a bash array using negative pattern matching and parameter expansion have unexpected results?

Tags: bash, wildcards, array

I'm doing a small-ish pure bash script to roll dice; as such I'm having to manipulate arrays. I want to do something akin to a `filter` operation in other languages: extract some of the things in the array, and put them in another.

I wish to retain the values as a bash array, as some other operations (namely slicing across indexes) are far easier to do with an array.

I could do it via a `for... do... done` loop, but I'm curious as to why my pattern matching does not work as expected.

```bash
shopt -s extglob;
dicerolls=(a b lol kek yolo swag ); 
c=(${dicerolls[@]/!(kek)/}); 
declare -p c;
# Expected: declare -a c=([0]="kek")
# Got: declare -a c=([0]="k")

# One can also see it with this example:
dicerolls=(20 15 7 8 9 0 14 5 6 200 144); c=(${dicerolls[@]/!(14)/}); declare -p c;
# Expected: declare -a c=([0]="14")
# Got: declare -a c=([0]="4")

# Oddly, this works for single-character values
dicerolls=(20 15 7 8 9 0 14 5 6 200 144); c=(${dicerolls[@]/!(8)/}); declare -p c;
# Got: declare -a c=([0]="8")
```

Edited-in simpler example from @ikkachu

```bash
var="abcd"
echo "${var/!(abcd)/}"
# Result: d
# Expected: abcd
```

It seems to correctly match (and discard) everything not in the pattern, but when encountering what is enclosed in the pattern, seems to only get the last (or first if one uses `${dicerolls[@]/%!(14)/}`) character of the match. I could not find in the manual anything relating to some kind of length limitation nor anything guaranteeing that the match isn't truncated.

I find this very odd, and did not find an explanation, let alone a 'fix' for this behavior.

The question, then, is this: is there a way, via pattern matching inside an array's parameter expansion to get the expected results above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> # Expected: declare -a c=([0]="kek")
> # Got: declare -a c=([0]="k")
> ```

I think we reduce that to something like this:

```
$ var="abcd"
$ echo "${var/!(abcd)/}"
d
```

And I *think* what happens is  similar to how `var="abbbcd"; echo "${var/a+(b)/}"` prints `cd`. The shell tries to find a match against the pattern `a+(b)`, starting at the start of the string, and looking for the longest match. `abbbcd` or `abbbc` don't match, but `abbb` does, and that part is removed.

<sub>(or rather, it likely starts at `a`, sees it matches the subpattern `a`, and continues to see that `ab`, `abb` and `abbb` match the whole pattern, but since `abbbc` doesn't, `abbb` is the longest match.)</sub>

Similarly, with the pattern `!(abcd)`, the whole string `abcd` does *not* match, but the substring `abc` matches. And is removed, leaving the `d`.

Or, in your case, `kek` does *not* match `!(kek)`, but `ke` does, leaving the `k`.

Similarly:

```
$ var="abcd"
$ echo "${var//!(a*)/}"
a
```

The whole string `abcd` does not match `!(a*)`, and neither does anything starting at the first `a`, so the matcher moves on to start at the second letter. `bcd` matches `!(a*)` and is removed.

That looks unintuitive, but it's similar to every other case where a match anywhere in the string counts. E.g. trying the pattern `b*e` against the string `abcdefg`, matches the `bcde` part at the middle of the string. It's just that with a negated pattern, the strings that match can vary wildly.

Anyway, you'd likely be better off with some other programming language, one that has better tools for working with data structure, e.g. the "filter" function.

Also note that even though it's somewhat useful for the filtering idea here, the unquoted expansion in `c=(${dicerolls[@]/!(kek)/});` would cause issues if any of your array elements contained white space or glob characters. A proper "filter" function would not have such an issue.

Comment: Ha. I see. It does make sense, if a bit odd. I would've thought that bash would keep its matches separate and not "pollute" them when expanding, i.e. in:

`var="abcd" ; echo "${var/!(abcd)/}"`

I would've thought that bash would "remember" that `abcd` has matched, and keep it safe, rather than replace the `abc` portion.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment: I would've thought that bash would run the pattern as a positive match (`${var/abcd/}`), discard the result (`''`) and save the rest (`abcd`), but this is not what is happening, and the source of my confusion.

Comment: @CyberFoxar, I'm not sure what "run the pattern as a positive match and discard the result" would mean... Especially since it's not that the whole pattern is negated, just that part of it. (E.g. you could have a pattern like `foo!(.txt)`.) Anyway, part of the problem here is that the pattern match is not locked to the start or the end of the string, so all the intermediate strings are possible matches, while for filtering, you probably want matches against the whole string.

Comment: Also, a few things are more logically done with separate matches, where the match itself is negated. E.g. `f+(o)!(.txt)` _does_ match `foo.txt`, again because `f+(o)` matches `fo`, and `!(.txt)` matches `o.txt`. (Something like `f+(o)!(o*|.txt)` might work, though, but...) So if one wants that, a condition like "match `f+(o)` at the start; and don't match `.txt` at the end" might be better. Or in regexes and AWK, `/^fo+/ && ! /\.txt$/`.